# uboot fails to execute load cmd from uboot.env

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot

I am working with

- U-boot v2021.10
- BeagleBone Black rev C

I've created an uboot.env image with `mkenvimage` tool from file

```
loadfromsd=load mmc 0:1 0x82000000 /zImage; load mmc 0:1 0x88000000 /am335x-boneblack.dtb
set_bootargs=setenv bootargs console=ttyS0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
uenvcmd=setenv auotload no; run set_bootargs; run loadfromsd; printenv bootargs; bootz 0x82000000 - 0x88000000
```

The problem is in files loading to memory with `load` cmd in first line.

Full message from start is:

```
U-Boot SPL 2021.10 (Oct 14 2021 - 20:41:20 -0700)
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2021.10 (Oct 14 2021 - 20:41:20 -0700)

CPU  : AM335X-GP rev 2.1
Model: TI AM335x BeagleBone Black
DRAM:  512 MiB
ti_sysc target-module@9000: failed to get fck clock
WDT:   Started with servicing (60s timeout)
NAND:  nand_base: timeout while waiting for chip to become ready
nand_base: No NAND device found
0 MiB
MMC:   ti_sysc target-module@7000: failed to get fck clock
OMAP SD/MMC: 0, OMAP SD/MMC: 1
Loading Environment from FAT... OK
<ethaddr> not set. Validating first E-fuse MAC
Net:   eth2: ethernet@4a100000, eth3: usb_ether
=> run uenvcmd
4295456 bytes read in 282 ms (14.5 MiB/s)
'ailed to load '/am335x-boneblack.dtb
bootargs=console=ttyS0,115200n8 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
Kernel image @ 0x82000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x418b20 ]
ERROR: Did not find a cmdline Flattened Device Tree
Could not find a valid device tree
```

Actual error is

```
=> run uenvcmd
4295456 bytes read in 282 ms (14.5 MiB/s)
'ailed to load '/am335x-boneblack.dtb
```

**P.S.** 
My u-boot fails to recognize ${} substitutions properly, and usage of

```
console=ttyS0,115200n8
bootpartition=mmcblk0p2
set_bootargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} root=/dev/${bootpartition} rw rootfstype=ext4 rootwait
```

caused and error

```
syntax error:
rootfstype=ext4 rootwait0n8
```

this 0n8 was appended after rootwait and shouldn't be there. So I've written this "straight" file without variables.

Comment: **UPD**.: when I enter ```load``` cmd manually in u-boot prompt - it works fine.

Comment: To be clear, you are literally seeing `'ailed to load` and not `Failed to load` ?  The code in question is `log_err("Failed to load '%s'\n", filename);` so I wonder if there's not some odd corruption going on here.

Comment: @TomRini yes! I it is ```'ailed to load ....'```. I just copied everything from PuTTY console.

Comment: @TomRini I cloned it from GitHub https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/ with cmd ```git clone -b v2021.10 https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot.git --depth=1```

Comment: U-Boot now has a `load` command?   Wouldn't that conflict with the existing `loads`, `loadb`, `loadx`, and `loady` commands?

Comment: A carriage return character at the end of the string, i.e. "/am335x-boneblack.dtb\r", would display on a terminal screen exactly as reported, i.e. overwrite the `F` that starts the line with the closing apostrophe..  No code corruption needed.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [sawdust](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599004/sawdust) for info that carriage return character matters and overrides first letter of error msg - I've got an idea that it also matters for path to file in `load` cmd, and it matters.

[image: space and \r after each line]

If I use space+\r, NOT just \r - everything works fine.

Comment: Your usage of carriage returns in these environment variables is unneeded and therefore bizarre.  That could also break variable substitutions as you experienced.  Therefore this is an incorrect solution, regardless of the apparent improvement.

Comment: @sawdust could you please provide an example ?

Comment: You mean an example of a *proper* environment variable? Pick any/all of your environment variables in your answer, and remove the trailing space and `CR`.